# Rolling forecast origin cross-validation in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, forecasting, arima

Probably a dumb post but here goes:

So as someone who has done some econometricks and ML like random forests and XGBoosts I always make sure to use either a k-fold cross validation or/and a train/test set approach (using caret), but I have a question about implementing rolling forecast origin in CV in forecasting models using the `ets()` function (and `arima`).

In my textbook it used the `tsCV` function when showing some basic forecasts like seasonal naive, but when moving to ets models using `ets()`, he just used the function with model parameters such as `"AAdM"`, then used the `forecast()` to make a forecast for 8 periods. I did not see any splitting of the data.

Does the `ets()` function do this automatically, or has the example probably been constructed to just show the elements of the ets model?

If it's the latter, then I should split the data using `rsample`. But then the question is, how do I for instance implement rolling CV when forecasting say the next 12 periods? A simple train/test split is easy, but I am not familiar with rolling forecasting origins and the book only briefly mentioned anything about cross validation.

Comment: Plus 1 for "econometricks";-)

Comment: On a more serious note: This is a fairly broad question and as such not a good fit for Stack Overflow at the moment. If this is about statistical understanding you might be better off asking this on Cross Validated. If this is about coding, please include a code example with sample data to illustrate what you've been trying to do, what didn't work, and what you'd like to get out.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about Cross Validated. I'll check it out